# Google Calendar API - list method not working when calendarId is set to 'primary'

Tags: python, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar's API to get the events of the day. The weird thing that's happening is when I use `calendarId='primary'` with the list method, no results are returned. However, if I input my email for the calendar, it works correctly. Any reason why that is?

Code:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient.discovery import build

import os
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def main():
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/path/to/keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    later = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=20)
    later = later.isoformat() + 'Z'
    print("Getting events for the day...")

    eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, timeMax=later, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When using service account as stated in this tutorial "[Google Calendar API with PHP – Service Account](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/), "By default a service account doesn't have access to any Calendars. You need to either create one using Calendars: insert or grant it access to one of your own calendars." Try sharing your main Calendar to the service account then try your code again and see if the result will still be `null`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I made sure to share the calendar with the service account and it still doesn't work. The list to populate the events is still empty.

Comment: @alecjstew did you fond a solution? I have the same problem